# C variable assignment issue

Tags: c

I think the title does not suit well for my question. (I appreciate it, if someone suggests an Edit) 
I am learning C with "Learn C The Hard Way.". I am using `printf` to output values using format specifiers. This is my code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    float y = 4.5;
    char c = 'c';

    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    printf("y=%f\n", y);
    printf("c=%c\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```

This works as I expect it to. I wanted to test it's behavior when it comes to conversion. So everything was ok unless I made it to break by converting `char` to `float` by this line:

```
printf("c=%f\n", c);
```

Ok, I'm compiling it and this is the output:

```
~$ cc ex2.c -o ex2
ex2.c: In function ‘main’:
ex2.c:13:3: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
printf("c=%f\n", c);
^
```

The error clearly tells me that It cannot convert from `int` to `float`, But this does not prevent the compiler from making an object file, and the confusing part is here, where I run the object file:

```
~$ ./ex2
x=10
y=4.500000
c=c
c=4.500000
```

As you can see `printf` prints the last `float` value it printed before. I tested it with other values for `y` and in each case it prints the value of `y` for `c`. Why this happen?

Comment: Please do not tag spam C questions with the C++ tag

Comment: @Mgetz The correct answer (undefined behavior) applies to [std::printf()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) as well. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ there are no C++ headers included in the question, it's still tag spam as the question is pure C

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: We tag questions, not answers.

Comment: @chris can you tell what does undefined behavior mean please?

Comment: @user3061142: Why not do some basic research?

Comment: OK, I see! Yes it's not really c++ :P ...

Comment: since the `int` argument doesn't corrupt the memory contents of where the `double` argument was before, there are 2 logical possibilities: (a) a fantastic coincidence of same bitpatterns, or (b) not overlapping location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler is warning you about the undefined behaviour you have. Anything can happen. Anything from seeming to work to nasal demons. A good reference on the subject is [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Normally, int can convert to double just fine:

```
int i = 10;
double d = i; //works fine
```

`printf` is a special kind of function. Since it can take any number of arguments, the types have to match exactly. When given a `char`, it is promoted to `int` when passed in. `printf`, however, uses the `%f` you gave it to get a `double`. That's not going to work.

Here is how one would implement their own variadic function, taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start):

```
int add_nums(int count, ...) 
{
    int result = 0;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += va_arg(args, int);
    }
    va_end(args);
    return result;
}
```

`count` is the number of arguments that follow. There is no way for the function to know this without being told. `printf` can deduce it from the format specifiers in the string.

The other relevant part is the loop. It will execute `count` times. Each time, it uses `va_arg` to get the next argument. Notice how it gives `va_arg` the type. This type is assumed. The function needs to rely on the caller to pass in something that gets promoted to `int` in order for the `va_arg` call to work properly.

In the case of `printf`, it has a defined list of format specifiers that each tell it which type to use. `%d` is `int`. `%f` is `double`. `%c` is also `int` because `char` is promoted to `int`, but `printf` then needs to represent that integer as a character when forming output.

Thus, any function that takes variadic arguments needs some caller cooperation. Another thing that could go wrong is giving `printf` too many format specifiers. It will blindly go and get the next argument, but there are no more arguments. Uh-oh.

If all of this isn't enough, the standard explicitly says for `fprintf` (which it defines `printf` in terms of) in C11 (N1570) §7.21.6.1/9:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

All in all, thank your compiler for warning you when you are not cooperating with `printf`. It can save you from some pretty bad results.

Comment: Thank you for your full complete answer

Answer (score 0):

Since `printf` is a varargs function, parameters cannot be converted automatically to the type expected by the function. When varargs functions are called, parameters undergo certain standard conversions, but these will not convert between different fundamental types, such as between integer and float. It's the programmer's responsibility to ensure that the type of each argument to `printf` is appropriate for the corresponding format specifier. Some compilers will warn about mismatches because they do extra checking for `printf`, but the language doesn't allow them to convert the type -- `printf` is just a library function, calls to it must follow the same rules as any other function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very general description, which may be slightly different depending on the compiler in use...

---

When `printf("...",a,b,c)` is invoked:

- The address of the string `"..."` is pushed into the stack.
- The values of each of the variables `a`, `b`, `c` are pushed into the stack:

  Integer values shorter than 4 bytes are expanded to 4 bytes when pushed into the stack.

  Floating-point values shorter than 8 bytes are expanded to 8 bytes when pushed into the stack.
- The Program Counter (or as some call it - Instruction Pointer) jumps to the address of function `printf` in memory, and execution continues from there.
- For every `%` character in the string pointed by the first argument passed to function `printf`, the function loads the corresponding argument from the stack, and then - based on the type specified after the `%` character - computes the data to be printed.

---

When `printf("%f",c)` is invoked:

- The address of the string `"%f"` is pushed into the stack.
- The value of the variable `c` is expanded to 4 bytes and pushed into the stack.
- The Program Counter (or as some call it - Instruction Pointer) jumps to the address of function `printf` in memory, and execution continues from there.
- Function `printf` sees `%f` in the string pointed by the first argument, and loads 8 bytes of data from the stack. As you can probably understand, this yields "junk data" in the good scenario and a memory access violation in the bad scenario.